# What are the disadvantages of uClibc?

Tags: embedded, libraries, c, glibc

I try to speed up my boot sequence, and somebody recommends to  use the uClibc instead of Glibc. I've built an image with it, it gets smaller and faster to boot — but at which cost?

Does anyone know the disadvantages of using uClibc as the C library?

Comment: In a nutshell, it's smaller but has fewer features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the official page: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/uclibc/Glibc_vs_uClibc_Differences.txt

Comment: after reading this, it sounds to me that the behavior of using `uClibc` is not really clear for every case - so try&error(?) and let's see what happens.